# How to redirect Windows cmd output to a text file?

Tags: windows, logging, cmd

I am trying to monitor the cmd output of a certain executable `.exe` and use it for another process running at the same time.

The problem is that all cmd redirecting functions **( '>','>>','<' and '|')** would only redirect the output after a successful return of the last command.

What I wanted to do is to generate some kind of streaming log of my **cmd**.

Comment: `> "somefile.ext" 2>&1`? `2> "somefile.ext"`?

Comment: A process has 3 standard File handles -- `StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, and `StandardError` -- which the CMD shell can redirect to a pipe or disk file, but a console application's behavior may change or break if the standard handles aren't console files. Note that the program's output is not "cmd output".  CMD only sets the inherited standard handles for OS resources (e.g. a console, pipe, or file-system file). In particular, CMD is not the console. It's a headless shell that can attach to a console and use console I/O files, exactly the same as any other Windows process.

Answer (score 5):

You can run in your process in background by using

`start /b something.exe > somefile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Windows 20H2:   Redirection works fine when logged in as true administrator but will NOT work when logged in as a created administrative user. I have used it for years to redirect the output of a multi target backup system using Hobo copy to put the console output in a log file. I have never been able to get it to work successfully in Windows 10 ver 19 or 20 on a created administrative user.

Answer (score -1):

You can prefix the command with "cmd /c" to start a new command prompt, and redirect the output of the command prompt:

```
cmd /c YOUR CODE > TextFileName.txt
```

> **Note** :  Use ONLY single greater than (>)

Since the output of **cmd** is going to TextFileName.txt.

Whereas this misses the error output, so you are not able to see :  **Request to UnKnown timed-out for each failed address.**

Comment: Still, opening a new cmd from the main on did not change the case. Anyways, the transfer to the file is pending the termination of the 'YOUR CODE' section.

Comment: YOUR CODE section Means - add your code which you want to run and then run the whole line.

Comment: Yes, yes I know. for instance this is my command line: 

`cmd / c my_executable.exe inputfile.txt 2>&1 executable.log` 

The output will be only available in 'excutable.log' after 'my_exexutable.exe' is fully executed. I am trying to stream the output into the log file not to harness it after the termination of the process

Comment: @weamelsahar you cannot see the error output. out will go to text file only when you don't face any error.

Comment: @weamelsahar, standard I/O to disk files and pipes is usually buffered by default, which is usually 4 KiB. The process flushes the buffer when the buffer is full or when it exits. Also, a pipe or disk file is not a console file. A program may only work properly with a console file. Search for winpty, which can adapt the console into a stream interface like a Unix pty. The Fall 2018 update for Windows 10 will include a [ConPTY API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/08/02/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty).

Comment: @eryksun, I am aware that as you mentioned earlier the program can be producing a `StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, or `StandardError` (@SolveProblem it is not just an error output). I simply checked that using `2>`, `1>`,`2>&1` and observing what was in the text log eventually.  The problem is the buffering of the output as you said. I realised that as long as I can't decompile my executable, I have to look for an App that would stream the output of the console for me. Nothing inherent in the cmd would do the job.